# How can I change a color channel in an image using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image where some color channels in the pixels have a value of zero (ie 255, 146, 0). I want to be able to change any value equal to zero in the array to a different value, but I do not know how to access these values. Any help with this?

This is the image array:

```
[[[ 76 163 168]
  [109 166 168]
  [173 172 167]
  ..., 
  [ 83 182 144]
  [ 78 172 134]
  [ 82 150 131]]

 [[ 51 151 168]
  [ 99 157 171]
  [173 195 159]
  ..., 
  [ 56 165 144]
  [ 25 198 125]
  [ 35 185 121]]

 [[ 76 163 121]
  [112 147 120]
  [175 151 118]
  ..., 
  [ 57 162 159]
  [ 36 185 132]
  [ 32 194  97]]

 ..., 
 [[ 78 189 126]
  [ 68 173 129]
  [ 58 171 150]
  ..., 
  [ 41 188 163]
  [ 34 176 126]
  [ 35 176 102]]

 [[131 155 161]
  [101 141 161]
  [ 42 151 177]
  ..., 
  [ 56 178 122]
  [ 45 192 114]
  [ 46 184 112]]

 [[130 157 185]
  [ 83 141 185]
  [ 42 158 185]
  ..., 
  [ 63 187  88]
  [ 45 194 102]
  [ 45 184 129]]]
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
img[(img==zero_val).all(-1)] = new_val
```

, where `zero_val` is the `zero` color and `new_val` is the new color to be assigned at those places where we have `zero` colored pixels.

Sample run -

```
# Random image array
In [112]: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(4,5,3))

# Define sample zero valued and new valued arrays
In [113]: zero_val = [255,146,0]
     ...: new_val = [255,255,255]
     ...: 

# Set two random points/pixels to be zero valued
In [114]: img[0,2] = zero_val

In [115]: img[2,3] = zero_val

# Use proposed approach
In [116]: img[(img==zero_val).all(-1)] = new_val

# Verify that new values have been assigned
In [117]: img[0,2]
Out[117]: array([255, 255, 255])

In [118]: img[2,3]
Out[118]: array([255, 255, 255])
```